# PHP Self Submitting Form Works in FF and Chrome but not IE (404 error)

Tags: php, forms

I'm a little stumped. I've been pulling my hair out tring to figure this out. The PHP self submitting form works fine in Fire Fox and Chrome but when I try it in IE, I receive a 404 error.

Here are my form tags:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
    name="New Policy/Procedure Form" id="form_name">

//content

<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you leave the form without action, the form will submit to the page itself.

Comment: +1 @FabricioMatte. You can either not apply the action attribute, or set the attribute property to a blank string. `action=""`

Comment: I've tried that but it still generates a 404 error.

Comment: What url generates the 404? If the page loads once, it should load twice... Are you sure it's a 404 and not a 500 error?

Comment: It's definitely a 404 error... I took the javascript out and still no luck! Damn IE!

Comment: PHP_SELF isn't working either - maybe because it's a Wordpress site?

Answer (score 2):

You should put `PHP_SELF` inside quotes: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`; if your error reporting settings allow PHP to generate the notice that it normally does for this, that would ruin your day.

Additionally (but far less likely) it's conceivable that `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` contains some "red flag" character for HTML markup. You should **always** use `htmlspecialchars` whenever you embed a non-fixed value inside HTML, including in this case:

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]); ?>"
```

[`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) has other parameters as well, the default values of which are OK most of the time (but not always). You should check them out and specify them explicitly.